# Scheduled tasks not preserving order with Dynamic?

Tags: core-language, asynchronous-processing

In studying the last Basic Example in the documentation for `StartScheduledTask`, namely

```
fun := With[{t = RandomInteger[{1, 3}]}, 
  Print["Waiting ", t, " seconds."]; Pause[t]]

RunScheduledTask[fun; StartScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {1}];

RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
```

I first noted that nothing `Print`s. That doesn't scare me too much; I would just guess that since the task is on another thread, it would have difficulty printing to the Notebook thread, and this might be a regression overlooked in recent versions (it doesn't print when evaluating directly in the documentation, either; MMA 9.0.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.9).

I decided to peek inside the task by making it assign something to a `Dynamic` that's on display in the Notebook, so I wrote

```
$foo = 1;

Dynamic[$foo]


RemoveScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[];
$foo = -1;
    $fun[] :=
  With[{t = RandomReal[]},
   $foo = ("Waiting " <> ToString@N[t, 2] <> " seconds.");
       Pause[t]];
    RunScheduledTask[$fun[];
 StartScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {1}];
```

When I run this, the value of `$foo` is updated with the random number `t`, but it seems to be *after* doing the `Pause`. In other words, let's say `t` has the following sequence of values

```
0.10000
0.90000
0.20000
```

Now, I can *feel* the difference between 0.1 seconds and 0.9 seconds and 0.2 seconds, and it feels like 0.1 is Displayed for 0.9 seconds, and the number 0.9 is displayed for 0.2 seconds, and so on. In other words, the display looks like

```
Waiting 0.10000 seconds   (* this displays for 0.9 seconds *)
Waiting 0.90000 seconds   (* this displays for 0.2 seconds *)
etc.
```

What's going on here?

Comment: The output of `Print[]` is going to the Messages window

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things that go wrong: first by restarting `$ScheduledTask` you are also reusing the delay of one second that you gave with `RunScheduledTask`. Second your `Pause` might start before the `Dynamic` fires (or is finished). This seems to work as expected (I am using a slightly more complicated `Dynamic` which lets me better see what happen as I don't feel I can judge time differences below 1 second reliable...):

```
$foo = 1; lastTime = AbsoluteTime[];
    Dynamic[Function[lastTime = #2; 
       Row[{DateString[{"Minute", ":", "Second"}], ":    ", 
         Round[(#2 - #1)] -> $foo}]
       ][lastTime, AbsoluteTime[]], TrackedSymbols :> {$foo}]

$fun[] := With[{t = RandomChoice[Range[4]] + 0.1*RandomReal[]},
       $foo = ("Waiting " <> ToString@N[t, 2] <> " seconds.");
   FinishDynamic[];
   Pause[t]
   ];

$foo = -1;
    RemoveScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[];
    RunScheduledTask[
      $fun[];
  StartScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask],
  {0.05}
  ];
```

The trick is to use `FinishDynamic` to let the `Dynamic` do its work before starting the `Pause` and also using only a very short delay in `RunScheduledTask`. When playing with this I found that there seems to be a problem with the general idea: it seems that the `Pause` within the scheduled task does block the kernel also for shift-return evaluations which might or might not be a problem for what you try to achieve. It certainly makes the FrontEnd feel very slow when used in the usual interactive way...